# Why doesn't showing newly added my source files to other crew on Xcode SVN?

Tags: xcode, svn

I'm using the subversion on Xcode6.1 and OSX Yosemite.

When I make new sources and commit it, new files are not shown to other developer by updating.

I found out that new files are added when the other developer select a project folder and click a mouse right button then execute "add files to PROJECTNAME" feature.

In Eclipse, I know new files are automatically added to package list when commit.

Is this a really correct way to update new files by manually finding and adding on Xcode?